# XML/XSL: Sum in foreach loop with conditional (special case)

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I have the following XML:

```
    <root>
 <groups>
  <group id="101">
   <number>10</number>
   <children>
    <leader id = "A" />
    <members>
     <member id="1">
     <member id="2">
     <member id="3">
    </members>
   </children>
  </group>
  <group id="102">
   <number>20</number>
   <children>
    <leader id = "A" />
    <members>
     <member id="4">
     <member id="5">
     <member id="3">
    </members>
   </children>
  </group>
  <group id="103">
   <number>30</number>
   <children>
   <leader id = "A" />
    <members>
     <member id="1">
     <member id="4">
     <member id="3">
    </members>
   </children>
  </group>
 </groups>

</root>
```

How can I sum the  property of all the member whom id = 1 using XSL?

Thanks

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression that produces the wanted sum. :)

Answer (score 6):

**Use**:

```
sum(/*/*/*/number[../children/members/member[@id=1]])
```

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "sum(/*/*/*/number
              [../children/members/member[@id=1]])
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (corrected the severely malformed provided text!):

```
<root>
    <groups>
        <group id="101">
            <number>10</number>
            <children>
                <leader id = "A" />
                <members>
                    <member id="1"/>
                    <member id="2"/>
                    <member id="3"/>
                </members>
            </children>
        </group>
        <group id="102">
            <number>20</number>
            <children>
                <leader id = "A" />
                <members>
                    <member id="4"/>
                    <member id="5"/>
                    <member id="3"/>
                </members>
            </children>
        </group>
        <group id="103">
            <number>30</number>
            <children>
                <leader id = "A" />
                <members>
                    <member id="1"/>
                    <member id="4"/>
                    <member id="3"/>
                </members>
            </children>
        </group>
    </groups>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
40
```

Comment: +1 for rigth answer and for taking the time to correct a "severely malformed" input! Ja!